# How to convert Gregorian calendar to Ethiopian calendar in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert Gregorian calendar dates to the Ethiopian calendar.For example: my variable (date_Gregorian) is "12/07/2016 ", "11/05/2015", "07/06/2011"...., I want to covert it to Ethiopian calendar with R. I found the code to convert Ethiopian calendar to Gregorian calendar, but not what I asked here. So Could anyone help to tell how I can do that with any package/function? Or help to revise this R code (Ethiopian to Gregorian calendar) to achieve the reversed purpose? Thanks a lot~~!

The code I found to convert Ethiopian Calendar to Gregorian Calender:

```
ethiopian_to_greg <- function(cmc = NULL){
  ey = trunc((cmc-1)/12)+1900
  em = cmc-(ey-1900)*12
  ed = 1
  
  joffset = 1723856
  n = 30*(em -1)  + ed - 1 # ed - 1 if actually 0
  jd = joffset + 365 + 365*(ey-1) + trunc(ey/4) + n
  
  z = jd + 0.5
  w = trunc((z-1867216.25)/36524.25)
  x = trunc(w/4)
  a = z+1+w-x
  b = a+1524
  c = trunc((b-122.1)/365.25)
  d = trunc(365.25*c)
  e = trunc((b-d)/30.6001)
  f = trunc(30.6001*e)
  day = b-d-f
  
  month = e-1
  
  month.low  <-(month<=12)*(e-1)
  month.high <-(month>12)*(e-13)
  month = month.low+month.high
  
  year.low <- (month < 3)*(c-4715)
  year.high <-(month>=3)*(c-4716)
  year = year.low + year.high
  
  outcmc = 12*(year - 1900)+month
  return(outcmc)
}
```

Comment: You should add the programming language in which you are trying to achieve this

Comment: https://github.com/hesohn/DHSmortality/blob/master/R/ethiopian_to_greg.R converts Ethiopian to Gregorian but not the other way. https://github.com/Zenysis/ethiopian-date  is a Python package, could access it via the `reticulate` package (but would need Python installed).  Can you give some examples so we can test whether we're getting it right?

Comment: for your second question, `?sprintf` or `?paste` would probably work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found those resources too. The current problems for me are: First, I want to know the code how to convert  Gregorian calendar to Ethiopian data not the current R code which the author converted Ethiopian calendar to Gregorian For example: my variable (date_Gregorian) is "12/07/2016 ", "11/05/2015"...., I want to covert it to Ethiopian calender; Second, my Ethiopian calendar data only has month and day, format is dd-mm, for example, the variable (date_Ethiopian) is "7.06", "22.05".....I dont know how to apply it to that current R code since I dont have year in my data. Thanks.

Comment: (1) If you found resources already, and especially if they don't solve your problem, it's good to note that in your question (to show that you've done your research and to save people the trouble of finding them themselves). (2) Can we please have a [mcve], i.e. a short example of some input (in R-friendly format) **and the desired output**?  I already hinted that you can use `paste()` or `sprintf()` to add a year (e.g. the current year) to a date string. (You're going to have to make *some* assumption about what year to use, as conversion of month/day data will depend on what year you're in!)

Comment: I just revised my question based on the answers, now the question is simplified like: how to convert Gregorian calendar to Ethiopian Calendar based on the opposite code you provided. My data is like date_gregorian<-c(12/07/2016 ", "11/05/2015", "07/06/2011"). Thanks~!